# Gradient identity for streamlines

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

I am studying a 2D flow and I have a resource telling me that the following holds true for streamlines in general. Let $f$ be the density of the flow, and suppose there exists a unique streamline connecting a point $x_I$ on the inflow boundary and $x_O$ on the outflow boundary. Then the following holds:

$$A_s u \cdot \nabla f = |u|(f(x_I) - f(x_O))$$

where $A_s$ is the length of the streamline and $u$ is the velocity field.

I do not see how this is true - can anyone explain and/or quote a resource for a proof?

Comment: If you consider a tiny streamline $x_O=x_I+\delta x$, can you see how you might derive it?

Comment: We have $\lim_{|\delta x|\rightarrow 0} |u| \frac{f(x_I + \delta x) - f(x_I)}{|\delta x|} = u \cdot \nabla f$, but that does not quite get me all the way.